# Data storage in taffy DB

Tags: angularjs, taffydb

I am building an application with Angular js and Taffy DB.

1.Where will be the data stored?In browser?

2.How to view the data stored?

3.How to select the data stored?

Please Advice

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the data is stored in an TAFFY object like an array variable in your code.
2. db().get();  - returns array with all stored data
3. db({column:value}).get(); - is like select * from table where column = value

Taffy don't trigger Angular scope update automatically, you need to do it manually.

more info : http://www.taffydb.com/writingqueries